# Is there a metric space where 2 + 2 = 5?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

First I want to say, sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I just started getting in the world of topology and metric spaces, and I'm not sure I fully understand the concepts yet.

Here's my understanding so far: a metric space is defined by its distance function, which assign a real number $d(x,y)$ to every pair $(x,y)$.

The space we are "used" to and mostly work with is the Euclidean space, defined by $d (x,y) = |y - x|$.

If we move to a different space with a different distance formula, will that change the arithmetic that we are used to? So for example, $1 + 1$ would no longer be equal to $2$?

This lead to my real question for this: is there a space where $2 + 2 = 5$? can we create one? what would be the definition of the distance function for that space?

Again, that's my whole understanding from today's session. I might be totally off with what I grasped, sorry if that's the case

Thank you very much.

Comment: The metric has *nothing* to do with arithmetic. Metric spaces don't have additive structure. There are *groups* which are metrizable. But it has nothing to do with them being metric spaces. In short, addition and metric are completely separate things. Sometimes we're lucky enough to have them coincide somehow, but that's not automatically going to happen.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah ok thanks, guess I will need to read a lot more about it. thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're welcome. (And for what it's worth, I don't think this question deserves a downvote.)

Comment: Integers mod 1 would have 2+2=5 as it would be the same as 0+0=0 where 0 is the only number in the system, Quite boring in some ways yet would be a solution here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila in R we can define a metric to have an additive structure (as the Euclidean norm does) but if we switch to another metric we don't "transfer" the arithmetic over with us.

Answer (score 3):

Even though $2+2$ won't be equal to $5$, you could use a different metric on the real line ( $d(x,y)=\frac54|x-y|$ instead of $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ ) so that $2+2=4$ is "$5$ units from $0$", distance-wise.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in this particular example $2$ is $2.5$ units away from $0$. But with some effort one could certainly construct one where $2$ is two units away from $0$ and $4$ is $5$ units away from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.  But it does come down to what we think 2 + 2 means.  I can easily invent a metric where $d(0,2) = 2$ and $d(2,4) = 2$ and $d(0,4) = 3$ (this obeys the triangle inequality that $d(0,4) \le d(0,2) + d(2,4)$) is if you *squint* and get very fuzzy in your definition of what "2 + 2" means, I can say with my pants not entirely on fire, that 2 + 2 =3.

But this is a trick.  If I define arithmetic by the metric, I pretty much can't declare the label by which I called "4" to "really" be actually 4.  Or if I define arithmetic to be a sort of "counting stick" then this metric doesn't really represent "adding".  In a way I'm defining my "counting stick" to be curved.

In fact this is precisely how the old fashioned slide-rules worked.  Here's a metric:  d(a,b) = |log (b) - log(a)|.  (I hope I did that right; I just thought of it just now.) Then for 1 < b< c, Then d(1,b) + d(b,c) = d(1, b*c).  This turns a + b into a*b.  Or as the old joke about the snakes on Noah's Ark being placed on wooden tables to get them to reproduce ....